# How do I stop a thread with a blocking function call?

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I'm uisng the `psutil` library in a thread, that posts my CPU usage statistics periodically. Here's a snippet:

```
class InformationThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):    
        while True:
            cpu = psutil.cpu_percent(interval=600) #this is a blocking call
            print cpu
```

I need to stop this thread but I can't seem to understand how. The method [`cpu_percent`](https://github.com/packages/psutil/blob/master/psutil/__init__.py#L470) is a blocking function that will block for 600 seconds.

I've been digging around and all the examples I saw relied on a tight-loop that checked a flag to see whether the loop should be interrupted but in this case, I'm not sure how to kill the thread.

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean. Do you want to stop the thread forever, i.e. "kill it"? As you said `cpu_percent` is blocking, so the thread should already block.

Comment: You could use multiprocessing.Process instead of threads, then put a tight-loop in the parent process that p.terminates()s the InformationProcess process once a certain condition is met.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set interval to 0.0 and implement a tighter inner loop in which you can check whether your thread should terminate. It shouldn't be difficult to time it so that the elapsed time between calls to `cpu_percent()` is roughly the same as 600.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a`stop()`method to your`InformationThread`class that terminates its`run()`loop as shown the following. But note that it won't unblock a`cpu_percent()`call already in progress.

```
class InformationThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.daemon = True  # OK for main to exit even if instance still running
        self.running = False
        self.status_lock = threading.Lock()

    def run(self):
        with self.status_lock:
            self.running = True
        while True:
            with self.status_lock:
                if not self.running:
                    break
            cpu = psutil.cpu_percent(interval=600)  # this is a blocking call
            print cpu

    def stop(self):
         with self.status_lock:
            self.running = False
```